# Is the URL which is opened on webview of iOS and Android accessible by the end user?

Tags: android, swift, webview, android-webview, wkwebview

I am having a requirement to open few URLs on webview for both my iOS and Android application and I am just not 100% sure that are these URLs safe? Can the end-user by any means access these URLs opened on the webview?

Comment: Are you trying to ask, `Can the URLs that I open via an intent be rerouted to other URLs that I cannot control?` Or something else?

Comment: Do you mean "Can the user edit/see the URL of the web view?"?

Comment: @Sweeper yes you are right.